# How do I track the time a person goes to a place?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables, database-relations

I'm working on creating a database for a gym to track the members info. I want to be able to track the times that people go so you will be able to see when it is busiest. I'm not sure how to go about this. Do I need to make a new table for the information of when a member goes or do I add it into the members or gyms table?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We need more background information to be able to help you out here. For example, we need to know about the current structure of your tables. To know whether some info should go into the members table or the gyms table, we need to know what data those tables contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add this to a different table. You could make a new table with user_id which is the same as the users ID in the user table. It would then be quite easy to tie the visits to the users, if that’s a point.

Answer (score 0):

Create a visits table with the following columns

- visitId
- memberId
- gymId
- entryTime
- exitTime

The GymId column may not be required if your member is linked to a gym but it depends on your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of "domain" models. From your question it appears you already have Member and Gym models.

I suggest introducing an Attendance model.

```
Attendance
  - UserId
  - CheckInDateTime
```

This would translate to a new database table called "attendance" with the corresponding columns.

In order to see when is the busiest time - I would execute a "select count" statement on the attendance table and "group by" the check_in_date column (truncate the time portion).

A note on persisting datetime values. It is recommended to store the datetime value in UTC timezone. Then you can have your application convert the timezone accordingly when viewing the data.